# Generic Types: Dynamically type check specific object properties: using key ~ value pair from Type A, in Generic Type B

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I currently have a type (FieldTypeProperties) that I want to enforce dynamic type checking when it's keys are passed to a function or object:

```js
export enum supportedFields{
    Text = "Text",
    Note = "Note",
    Number = "Number"
}

export type FieldTypeProperties = {
    [supportedFields.Text]: TypeA;
    [supportedFields.Note]: TypeB;
    [supportedFields.Number]: TypeC;
};
```

I've managed to define a function that behaves as expected:

```js
const createField = <K extends keyof FieldTypeProperties>(fieldType: K, properties: FieldTypeProperties[K]): IResult => {

  let field: IResult;

  //Some code

  return field;

}
```

The usage works as expected and the fieldType argument value does check for the correct Type in the properties argument:

```js
let test = createField(supportedFields.Note, {});
// Checks for Type B in the properties argument, as defined in the FieldTypeProperties type
```

However for batch operations, I want to loop an array of objects that conform to the arguments in createField(), so:

```js
type BatchObj<K extends keyof FieldTypeProperties> = {
    fieldType: K;
    properties: FieldTypeProperties[K];
}

// Intended Usage:
let testBatch1: BatchObj<keyof FieldTypeProperties>[] = [
  {
    fieldType: supportedFields.Text,
    properties: {}, //Type A should only be checked, but it's not, instead a union of TypeA | TypeB | TypeC is checked
  },
]

// Usage that works but is NOT desired:
let testBatch2: BatchObj<supportedFields.Text>[] = [
  {
    fieldType: supportedFields.Text,
    properties: {}, //Type A is checked, but now any additional objects added to this array must have a fieldType = supportedFields.Text and properties = TypeA
  }
]
```

I can understand why this is happening, since in testBatch1:
fieldType (K) would the **set of keys** for the FieldTypeProperties type, and properties (FieldTypeProperties[K]) would be the **set of** values for the FieldTypeProperties type.

Is there a way to achieve my desired usage, based on what is inferred in the code snippet above? Or is this a typescript limitation and as it stands is not a possibility?

Your responses will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a union for each possible key : `BatchObj<"Text"> | BatchObj<"Note"> | BatchObj<"Number">` using the distribution of conditional types. This will ensure the relationship between `fieldType` and `properties` is preserved:

```
type BatchObj<K extends keyof FieldTypeProperties> = {
    fieldType: K;
    properties: FieldTypeProperties[K];
}
type BatchObjUnion<K extends keyof FieldTypeProperties = keyof FieldTypeProperties>  = K extends K ? BatchObj<K>: never

// Intended Usage:
let testBatch1: BatchObjUnion[] = [
  {
    fieldType: supportedFields.Text,
    properties: { text: "" }, //Type A
  },
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwM7LJWwAmAYgJbAA2+GA3gFBz1wAqo8AvHAETMgwcA0dBgDkIMYHHYcRY-oPpC0AI2BQJnBamVQONAL40aMAJ5hxjE8ADCaqnBSaVALjtKVcfcdNMLAIRt2IfGBnDBgoYkQAc3dDC29TAEF-MR4QsIjo-QixKAAzAEMAY3EASQAlYCwyeCp9UFx4T3EScnxzUwAFKAhTWFIMGzk4AG0sHGgxIlIKDAA6bhgAXWd24ASAbiHR7AaCFpnZ6WBl+OAfTYYRsd2p1rmNLRPVy03dTZpCiERQuEKoYHyYn2+DUAB4ANIIHhIShwADWwCMEFycGBqy6PRUMH6AD4ABS5aZtCzOcF8OBgbq9bGVZxoiwY6n9YbgxYASmc5UqyGqEhxcFo9H+MGQUEQLjIZAAhO99LEvD5AYUABYAeUUACsIVCxIhYQikSj6Z0qVjcYNLoTWqtSRcGJTMX1aaiiejTU6MCzFq95eJFTAVeqNQBVRDEL7algwgYG5Eu60M900gbsWNG12Jx3J-lqSFRvUDSEAfjg-sDmohOOciGAADcVAYAPSNuAlRC6oIg4MYfKRYI0MjARqVGBl5UARmcY6DofDiGGizUw0EgoYVooNswOwmeyJcwWAkuDqZztsKRgzg4HHc5ObqzgCUEugEiwMQA)

Comment: Bravo sir! This is exactly what was needed :). 
If one wants to understand distribution of conditional types better and how to construct more advanced types, are there any resources that you recommend?

Comment: @dylanwhittaker I don't have a lot of resources other than the handbook. You can checkout my TS talks on my profile. My 3h TS Conf workshop is a pretty comprehensive look at advanced types  https://youtu.be/27fL-rUXrJM